# how to update all keys of a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I Have hash like this

```
a={"Feb-13"=>"24176", "Aug-13"=>0, "May-13"=>0, "Jun-13"=>0, "Apr-13"=>0, "Oct-13"=>0, "Nov-13"=>0, "Jul-13"=>0, "Sep-13"=>0, "Jan-13"=>0, "Mar-13"=>0, "Dec-13"=>0}
```

but i need the same hash like this

```
a={"Feb"=>"24176", "Aug"=>0, "May"=>0, "Jun"=>0, "Apr"=>0, "Oct"=>0, "Nov"=>0 }
```

Is any other method like hash update.

Comment: Many keys from the first Hash missing in the second Hash you provided.

Comment: The best solution is to not create the first hash to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

```
a={"Feb-13"=>"24176", "Aug-13"=>0, "May-13"=>0, "Jun-13"=>0, "Apr-13"=>0, "Oct-13"=>0, "Nov-13"=>0, "Jul-13"=>0, "Sep-13"=>0, "Jan-13"=>0, "Mar-13"=>0, "Dec-13"=>0}

Hash[a.map { |k, v| [k[0...3], v] }]
# => {"Feb"=>"24176", "Aug"=>0, "May"=>0, "Jun"=>0, "Apr"=>0, "Oct"=>0, "Nov"=>0, "Jul"=>0, "Sep"=>0, "Jan"=>0, "Mar"=>0, "Dec"=>0}
```

Comment: `k[/.../]` had me confused for a moment. `k[0...3]` is a much clearer way to get a substring by length.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?:

```
a.inject({}) { |initial, (k,v)| initial[k[0..2]] = v; initial }

#=> {"Feb"=>"24176",
 "Aug"=>0,
 "May"=>0,
 "Jun"=>0,
 "Apr"=>0,
 "Oct"=>0,
 "Nov"=>0,
 "Jul"=>0,
 "Sep"=>0,
 "Jan"=>0,
 "Mar"=>0,
 "Dec"=>0}
```

Or:

```
Hash[a.map{ |x, y| [x[0..2], y] }]
#=> {"Feb"=>"24176",
 "Aug"=>0,
 "May"=>0,
 "Jun"=>0,
 "Apr"=>0,
 "Oct"=>0,
 "Nov"=>0,
 "Jul"=>0,
 "Sep"=>0,
 "Jan"=>0,
 "Mar"=>0,
 "Dec"=>0}
```

Comment: Oops. That was unintentional. Can you correct it by editing.? :-)

Comment: do change `[x.scan(/\w+/)[0], y]` to `[x[0..2], y]`.. But other answer did it already.. sad :o

Answer (score 1):

```
> Hash[a.map{|k,v| [k[/\w+/], v]}]
# => {"Feb"=>"24176", "Aug"=>0, "May"=>0, "Jun"=>0, "Apr"=>0, "Oct"=>0, "Nov"=>0, "Jul"=>0, "Sep"=>0, "Jan"=>0, "Mar"=>0, "Dec"=>0}
```